# Best place to fetch 3rd party data in ES/CQRS

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing

I have a RegisterUserCommand with some user data.

To be able to register user with some additional information, I need to connect to 3rd party so my question is:

1) Should Command already have all of that 3rd party data when called?

2) Would it be ok if CommandHandler connects to 3rd party and retrieves it?

3) I don't think that my aggregate root should be doing it but in a sense, it is domain logic.

I think that #2 is the best way but would like to hear if I'm going wrong about it or not?

(actual case is not registering user but it needs to fetch data from a remote service/3rd party)

Comment: Is the information 100% necessary in order to add the user to your domain, then the command handler should get the information. If not, add the user to the domain and let the "UserCreated" event fetch the data.

Comment: Yeah, 3rd party data is crucial at this stage.

BTW. How would I do it by event? I mean, arent commands (or actually command handlers) only ones that should be changing aggregates?

Comment: Could you provide some code? As it is, this question is very ambiguous.

Comment: Yeah sorry, question is ambiguous by design. I was trying to find a best practice for the general idea, not the particular case :(

Answer (score 0):

The issue with (2) that your domain layer (where the command handler definitely belongs) become dependent on an external bounded context. This breaks the onion architecture inner layer isolation.

Your first point is basically correct for some cases, if your service layer can fetch this data and send a self-contained command, this is one of possible solutions.

Another solution that instead of invoking a command handler, you can send a message to start a process manager that will send an information collection request, get the data back and send a command to your handler with all information required. Since this happens via asynchronous messaging, you will not have synchronous dependency on a third party and your application will keep working even if the third party is down, at least to some extent, and when the third party will wake up, all queued requests will be processed.

Usually, durable messaging also has some retry capabilities that decrease the risk of the request made to the external bounded context to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your 3rd party data is not part of your domain but is required by it so you could have a command that results in a "data requested" event to which an external process subscribes to.  This process could then gather the required 3rd party data and package it into another command which results in another event stating that the data was provided which would cause your query data to be update.